# Linked List Implementing Sorting Method

Tags: java, sorting

i made the linked list its not from java collections and i put in it many methods .. my linked list worked like the original one but theres a small differences my class have a **print** and **sort** **methods** **my input is : [5,18,3,10,2] ... or it can be a string inputs** .. i want the sort method to sort the linked list , so the **output should be like this : [2,3,5,10,18] or a sorted string**
here is the sort method code  :

```
        public void sort(){
        Node<E> current = head ;
        Node<E> current2 = current.next;
        E min = head.element;
        E temp;
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if(current2 != null){
                    if(min.compareTo(current2.element) > 0){
                      pos = j ;
                      min = current2.element;

                    }
                    current2= current2.next;
                }
            }

            temp = current.element;
            current.element = min;
            current = current.next;
            min = current.element;
            current2 = head;
            for (int j = 0; j <= pos; j++) {
                if(current2 !=null){
                if(j==pos){current2.element = temp;}
                current2= current2.next;
                } 
            }
            current2 = current.next;   
    }
}
```

[heres the full code](https://pastebin.com/ckaDaxBQ)

Comment: `i tried so hard but it didnt work` What doesn't work? Is there any error? If yes, please post the full stacktrace here. Also, it would be useful to have a minimal complete example which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @BackSlash Ok ,i edited it

Comment: A complete example is still missing. Add a complete program with sample data which demonstrates the issue

Comment: @BackSlash here's the full code : https://pastebin.com/ckaDaxBQ

Comment: @AbdulRahman we are not asking for the full code. We are asking for an example. What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your observed output? The pasted code will not compile since you call `print()` on an `LinkedList`, but a `LinkedList` has no method `print()`.

Comment: Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/sort-arraylist-in-descending-order-in-java/

Comment: i dont want it ready method ... i want to write it in my class (implement it)
its like an  excise  for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this sort method.

```
public void sort()
  {
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      Node<E> finalNode = head;
      Node<E> tempNode = head;

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
        E val1 = head.element;
        Node<E> nextnode = head.next;
        E val2 = nextnode.element;
        if (val1.compareTo(val2))
        {
          if (head.next.next != null)
          {
            Node<E> CurrentNext = head.next.next;
            nextnode.next = head;
            nextnode.next.next = CurrentNext;
            if (j == 0)
            {
              finalNode = nextnode;
            }
            else
              head = nextnode;

            for (int l = 1; l < j; l++)
            {
              tempNode = tempNode.next;
            }

            if (j != 0)
            {
              tempNode.next = nextnode;

              head = tempNode;
            }
          }
          else if (head.next.next == null)
          {
            nextnode.next = head;
            nextnode.next.next = null;
            for (int l = 1; l < j; l++)
            {
              tempNode = tempNode.next;
            }
            tempNode.next = nextnode;
            nextnode = tempNode;
            head = tempNode;
          }
        }
        else
          head = tempNode;
        head = finalNode;
        tempNode = head;
        for (int k = 0; k <= j && j < i - 1; k++)
        {
          head = head.next;
        }

      }
    }
  }
```